# (Android) Find path /Android in internal storage

Tags: android, path, android-sqlite

Is there a method in Android that returns the data path on internal storage?

I have 2 Android smartphone (Samsung s2 and s7 edge) where i installed an application. I want to take a sqliteDB situated in this path:

```
/Android/data/application.most/files/most_db
```

The problem is that in Samsung s2 i must use this path to take the DB:

```
private static final String db_path = "/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/org.application/files/application_db";
```

Instaed, in s7 i must use this:

```
private static final String db_path = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/application.most/files/application_db";
```

I want to take this path independently by device.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think that what you're looking for is something like that

```
String path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: Which package is getFilesDir() in?

Comment: Any "Context" package is a fit whether it is an Application/Activity/Fragment etc.

Answer (score 2):

Once change your Logic in different versions..
till android 4.xx it take internal memory as `/storage/sdcard0/`
where as from 4.4 kitKat it will take path as `/storage/emulated/0/`

Design [multiple apk](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/api.html) depending on android API versions...

your problem is solved.. you can install it in s2 with that path and S7 with this path...

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to Access Applications External Directory.
ie. "sdcard/Android/data/yourPackage/files"

You should use:
    **getExternalFilesDir(null)** method of **Context** Class.

```
private static final String db_path = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/application_db";
```

OR you can Directly get File Instance like:

```
File file = new File(getExternalFileDir(null),"application_db");
```

Make Sure you add **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** Permission in the Manifest.

You can read more about this at : 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)