# How could I create a file in the "Internal Storage" Directory?

Tags: android, android-storage

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6. I'm currently working on a test application where I would like quick access to a folder with my files.

Using the provided "My Files" Application, it specifies that all those folders are in the "Internal Storage" folder.

I know that internal storage is private, but I want to create a folder in the default folder that windows accesses when the phone is plugged in.
For example, the following code does not create the directory in the correct location.

```
File storage = new File("/testappplication");
if(!storage.exists()) {
   storage.mkdir();
   System.out.println("Folder Created");
}
```

I just want to know the path where to create the folder. Many other applications have storage here, so I know its possible.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497566/android-find-path-android-in-internal-storage) or/and [this : Environment.getDataDirectory()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724706/how-to-get-my-android-device-internal-download-folder-path)

Comment: Creating a file in Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/TestApplication/" doesn't seem to make the directory still.

Comment: do you ask to get permission?

Comment: @MehranZamani No I do not. Do I need to request for permissions outside of applying WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Comment: what's your target sdk?

Comment: Marshmello is my target SDK

Comment: do you get any error? how can you say that it isn't created? where do you look?

Comment: Beside checking, if I re-run the application, the code is executed to create the folder again.

Comment: did you use `getFilesDir()`? use it and if you got same issue, debug it using breakpoint in if statement to see the value of `storage` variable.

Comment: Just tried it as well. Could this be a permission issue? As well this path isn't what I want either.

Comment: no, api level upper than 23 have to ask for permission.

Comment: My apologies. getFilesDir is correct and is working. Enviorment.getDataDirectory() and Enviorment.getExternalStorageDirectory() are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while later I found the answer to this question.

```
public void createDirectory() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/test");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
        Log.w("DEBUG", "Created default directory.");

    }
}
```

This is how you create it code wise. The reason it wasn't creating was due to Samsungs weird permissions.

Make sure you have the storage permission enabled in Settings -> Apps -> App Name -> Permissions. I needed to turn it on so it would create the folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a directory inside the internal storage of the device. Except you've a root access for the app.

So, the following code won't work:

```
File storage = new File("/testappplication");
```

Because it tell the app to create a `testappplication` in the **root** folder.

You can only create the directory inside your app private folder within the following path:

```
String path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
```

And make the folder using the path.

Or you can use something like this:

```
File folder = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "testappplication");
if (!folder.exists()) {
    folder.mkdirs();
} else {
  // folder is exist.
}
```

Read more at [Saving Files](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Comment: I understand that, but I don't see how these other files have been created?
http://renegadeeagle.co/pics/NVIDIA%20Share_2017-07-23_02-55-46.png
All of these files came from somewhere, and I want to create one similar like this.

Comment: Ohh.. I see. Then you need to use [getExternalStorageDirectory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory())

Comment: I tried that as well, unfortunately Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/TestApplication/" isn't creating the file either.

Answer (score 0):

First just for trial make **runtime permmision** and then try the following code

```
 private void createInternalFile() {
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+getApplicationContext()
            .getPackageName()+"/File/profile");
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
    } }
```

then check your internal storage in which you will find a folder whose name is your package name